# R Convert group_by table to new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have grouped by data like this

```
by_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(HP = sum(hp))
```

And I would like to convert this table from

| cyl | gear | HP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 4 | 608 |
| 4 | 5 | 204 |
| 6 | 3 | 215 |
| 6 | 4 | 466 |
| 6 | 5 | 175 |
| 8 | 3 | 2330 |
| 8 | 5 | 599 |

To something like cyl as columns and gear as rows

|  | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 97 | 215 | 2330 |
| 4 | 608 | 466 | - |
| 5 | 204 | 175 | 599 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple pivoting task, you can do it with `tidyr`'s [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(HP = sum(hp)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(gear, names_from = "cyl", values_from = "HP")

# A tibble: 3 x 4
   gear   `4`   `6`   `8`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    97   215  2330
2     4   608   466    NA
3     5   204   175   599
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `pivot_wider` -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(by_cyl, names_from = cyl, values_from = HP, values_fn = sum)

#   gear   `4`   `6`   `8`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3    97   215  2330
#2     4   608   466    NA
#3     5   204   175   599
```

Or with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(by_cyl), gear~cyl, value.var = 'HP', fun.aggregate = sum)
```